# Changing product is_purchasable in WooCommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, product

While developing a **WooCommerce** plugin which adds custom products to shoppin cart, I am using the function `add_to_cart` inside the `class-wc-cart.php`. But after updating woocomerce to latest version I receive the error.

> Sorry, this product cannot be purchased.

because inside the function `add_to cart`, the section `$product_data->is_purchasable()` started to return `false`. I debugged a find out that the reason why `is_purchasable()` returns false is that `get_price()` function. Because this function returns empty as price, hence woocommerce tells me the product is not purchasable because of empty price.

The product has a price and can be added to the cart using the interface. The plugin was working fine with old version of woocommerce. Let me know if you need more data.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the necessary changes using and removing `'' !== $product->get_price()` from the **`IF`** statement, this way:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'customizing_is_purchasable', 20, 2 );
function customizing_is_purchasable( $purchasable, $product ){
    if( $product->exists() && ( 'publish' === $product->get_status() || current_user_can( 'edit_post', $product->get_id() ) ) )
        $purchasable = true; 

    return $purchasable;
}
```

For product variations, you can also try at the same time *(untested, but it should work)*:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variation_is_visible', 'customizing_variation_is_visible', 20, 4 );
function customizing_variation_is_visible( $visible, $product_id, $parent_id, $product ){
    if( 'publish' === get_post_status( $product->get_id() ) )
        $visible = true;
    else
        $visible = false;

    return $visible;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: I am using `is_purchasable` function inside the `class-wc-product-variation`. This function also checks `variation_is_visible`, and the content of `variation_is_visible` also checks `get_price`. So hooking only to `is_Purchasable` not working by itself. I tried to do the same for `variation_is_visible` by looking your code but failed. Can you  add this filter ? (I couldn't find how to write if statement) -> `return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_variation_is_visible', 'publish' === get_post_status( $this->get_id() ) && '' !== $this->get_price(), $this->get_id(), $this->get_parent_id(), $this );`

Comment: Thank you much, but now the product is added to my cart with a price of 0. So actually I am back to the start point which is "Why `get_price` is returning empty". As this is the root cause of why `add_to_cart` not working, and `is_purchasable` was not returning true. You edited my question's title but I am not sure this is reflecting the problem. What do you think?

Comment: @HOY  I don't catch as I was thinking that you were complaining about products with zero price not added to cart… Your problem is really not well worded and kind of unclear... You should try to clarify what you have and what you really want with details, as nobody is able to help you actually. **For your initial question title: "Add To Cart not working on WooCommerce 3.X.X" is very large and doesn't reflect your specific problem** …